# PHP - MYSQL DateTime sorting

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

I am storing date in mysql datetime filed in following manner:

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

it stores datetime like this :  `2012-12-19 14:36:42`

Now I want to fetch following data using mysql query:

```
1) all the data 12 hours old

2) all the data 24 hours old
```

How can I get that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: date < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR))  .. but not giving desired result

Comment: `date < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)) ` I think

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date`>(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR))
```

`now()` returns current datetime.
`DATE_SUB` substracts the given second parameter (which can be minutes, hours, days..) from the first parameter.

We are simply checking if the date is bigger than the date 12 hours ago.

More on Mysql datetime functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: shouldn't it be `date <`  than `date >` ??

Comment: "12 hours old" would actualy mean = operator. So yeah, if you want older than 12 hours, use <, if younger than 12 use >.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_time, end_time) =24  
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_time, end_time) =12
```

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff also

Comment: -1, code dumps are not answers.  What is this?  Why does it work?  What's `TIMESTAMPDIFF`?  What does it do?

Comment: @Charles OP just asked "How can I get that?" . Also you are always free to post answers with full explainations, instead of downvoting everone else's posts

Comment: Maybe you should put some effort into your answers.  Code dumps are useless.  They teach nothing but that one can copy/paste their way to success.

Comment: Teaching every OP about SQl or Regular expressions are out of scope of stackexchange. This site is about answers and not teaching every basics of technologies. If they need clarifications, they can search net or can post questions or comments

Comment: "[If you give a man a fish he is hungry again in an hour. If you teach him to catch a fish you do him a good turn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)."  Handing out copy/paste solutions is bad.

Comment: Does everybody have to learn fishing , so that he can eat fish? Nobody cultivates a tea estate only to drink tea for himself